# Load all exist textures for XNA application

Tags: .net, xna, textures

In XNA application I can load some textures:

```
Texture2D texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("myTexture");
```

Can I get list of all exist textures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, yes you can ... albeit in a roundabout sort of way. You can easily create your own subclassed instance of a ContentManager, and in this custom instance do all the tracking that you want. So in your overridden load method, you can log the name of the texture any time you're loading a Texture2D.

Shawn Hargreaves has some great examples of how you can customize a content manager:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2007/03/09/contentmanager-readasset.aspx

Answer (score 3):

No, the best you can do is list all files inside a directory and load each file separately (with a loop).

Here is an example on how to do that: http://danielsaidi.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/xna-load-all-content-files-in-a-folder/